# regex=>lookahead between two matches c#

Tags: regex, c#-4.0, regex-lookarounds

```
const string numericReg = "\\d+"; // Matches a digit character. Equivalent to [0-9].
const string realNumsReg = numericReg + b + "(\\." + b + numericReg + ")?";
        const string b = "\\s*";
```

This statement is true :

```
  private const string rte = "(?<rate>" + realNumsReg + ")" +
                            "(?=(?<rte1>" + b + "qs " + "))";
```

and

This statement is true :

```
 private const string barl = "(?<barl>" + numericReg + ")" +
                                    "(?=((?<q>" + b + "point to print )))";
```

this is true for rte :

```
  MatchCollection s = Regex.Matches
                ("3000 qs / min", rte , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

this is true for barl:

```
  MatchCollection s = Regex.Matches
                ("6 point to print  ", barl , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Why is this wrong?

```
  MatchCollection s = Regex.Matches
                ("6 point to print  3000 qs/ min", barl+b+rte  , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 0):

First problem:
The comma (',') in the 3,000.
The first Matches is matching "000 rds"
There is nothing to match the "3," in the third Regex.Matches.

The second (less obvious problem):

The two look ahead assertions (?=*expression*), are assertions not matches, so nothing is matching whatever is inside the first assertion in the third Regex.

In your case: 'barl' + 'b' + 'rte'

'barl' matches the '6'  in '6 barrels per mounting', 'b' matches the space between '6' and 'barrels' ('barrels per mounting' are asserted by the look-ahead but not matched) and 'rte' cannot match a number followed by 'rds'.

Just remove the comma and lookaheads from your expression you don't really need them since the groups you're interested in are named anyway and what they match can be easily obtained from the Groups collection in the Match.

Improvements:

1. You might want to change rte to also match the '/ min' in 'qs / min' not just the qs.
2. Change numericReg to @"\d+(,\d{3})*(.\d+)?" (match any number of digits following by zero or more comma and exactly 3 digits groups and one or zero groups of a dot followed by digits). This regex matches numbers of the forms: 3000 3,000 3,000.0000

Comment: You mean that is not the only problem. The other problem I had not spotted earlier are the lookahead assertions (?=). I'm editing my response to include this error.